# Setting up and activating virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, django, windows, visual-studio-code

So, I've been trying to activate my virtual environment in VScode so I could open my Django manage.py and run the server, but for some reason it doesn't seem to activate in my bash terminal. And after running it, I get a "did you forget to activate your virtual environment?". What am I missing here?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run manage.py in a bash terminal. Is this in WSL or Git Bash or something else? What exact command did you run? Did you run source the activate script? What is the path to your virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

In the env folder, there should be an "activate.bat" script, that you can execute to activate your venv.

Comment: yea and run venv/Scripts/activate.bat in my terminal but I get no indication that it's activated even after creating a new terminal.

Comment: @RobHereHelp Usually the command prompt will update with the name of the virtual environment if it is activated successfully. Alternatively, you can run  `which python` to verify it is the interpreter you want.

Comment: After running it I "/Python/Python310/python".

Comment: @RobHereHelp After running what? What was the exact command?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should open bash in the existing directory and run Scripts\activate

I'd also like to confirm which of the virtual environment you are making use of.